# Does "use strict" apply to functions declared in a strict scope?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm getting this in jshint,

> [L16:C13] W034: Unnecessary directive "use strict".

However my question is does something like this work..

```
function () {
    "use strict";

    var a = function () {
        //stuff, (is this also strict)
    }

}
```

will *stuff* be strict too? Obviously something outside of the strict declaration won't be strict. But do other functions inside start out non-strict or inherit the strictness?

Answer (score 6):

## Yes, it will be strict; and, the strict-ness is inherited.

Any sub-scopes of anything with `"use strict";` will also be strict. There is **no need** that I can see to declare every function *strict* if you can declare an encapsulating scope strict.

I tried invoking the function both inside of the scope, and outside of the scope to make sure it didn't make a difference. This is a test that is run with `mocha`

```
var assert = require('assert');

var inside = function () {
    "use strict";
    var a = inside.a = function () {
        bar = 1;
        return bar;
    };
    var b = inside.b = function () {
        var bar = 1;
        return bar;
    };
    var c = inside.c = function () {
        "use strict";
        bar = 1;
        return bar;
    };
    var d = inside.d = function () {
        "use strict";
        var bar = 1;
        return bar;
    };

    describe('Inside Context', function () {
        it('inside a (no strict, no var)', a )
        it('inside b (no strict, var)', b )
        it('inside c (strict, no var)', c )
        it('inside d (strict, var)', d )
    } );

};

inside();

describe('Outside Context', function () {
    it('outside a (no strict, no var)', inside.a )
    it('outside b (no strict, var)', inside.b )
    it('outside c (strict, no var)', inside.c )
    it('outside d (strict, var)', inside.d )
} );
```

Here we see that both inside and outside without declaring the variable with var we have a test-failure indicating that strict is working:

```
Inside Context
  1) inside a (no strict, no var)  // fail
  ✓ inside b (no strict, var) 
  2) inside c (strict, no var)     // fail
  ✓ inside d (strict, var) 

Outside Context
  3) outside a (no strict, no var)  // fail
  ✓ outside b (no strict, var) 
  4) outside c (strict, no var)     // fail
  ✓ outside d (strict, var)
```